# Failed devise login not showing error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have an old rails app which used to use Devise 2 but since it never showed any flash or error messages I decdided to upgrade it to the latest hoping it would help. It didn't. I googled a lot and all that but no success.

Now, I got rails 3.2.21 and devise 3.4.1. I have no custom controllers and all views generated are only slightly changed. When I log in and fill in the correct credential, I get logged in. When I type in the wrong credentials, this is logged:

```
Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-08 19:27:33 +0100
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JwzYm4gLuXINZxDUsy4+hRIE5uZbFM7oWKwqKXR7ET0=", "user"=>{"email"=>"Patrick.Bartels@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 0.5ms
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JwzYm4gLuXINZxDUsy4+hRIE5uZbFM7oWKwqKXR7ET0=", "user"=>{"email"=>"Patrick.Bartels@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_sidebar.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21.6ms (Views: 20.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

No flash or error messages are being displayed. `application.html.erb`:

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| -%>
  <div class="message <%= type %>">
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end -%>
```

and `sessions/new.html.erb`:

```
<h2>Einloggen</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  <div><%= f.label :email, 'E-Mail' %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :password, 'Passwort' %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me, 'Login merken?' %></div>
  <% end -%>
  <div><%= f.submit "Einloggen" %></div>
<% end %>
<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

Can anyone tell me what's wroing with this and why it's not showing the flash/error messages?

Comment: is this still an issue for you?

Comment: ok, could you post your CSS that is being applied when the devise alerts are shown

Comment: I checked the code with FireBug but there are no flash messages or DOM elements to apply CSS to.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is an example of what i have used in the past to render messages

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-<%= key.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'danger' %>" role="alert">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
       <%= value if value.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

let me know if that works for you